# How to read text files(.txt) from file system using reader and pass each file's text to processor spring batch?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I wanted to create spring batch project that which can read files(.txt only) from a file system and pass the text of each file to the processor. Suppose i will use that text to covert uppercase in processor and wanted to save in single using custom writer.

Answer (score 0):

To read a file from filesystem you can try below approach and can modify as per your actual requirement, internally it will be all same its just matter of which way you would want to go for, THIS APPROACH IS JAVA WAY OF DOING NOT ANY FRAMEWORK SPECIFIC.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class FileExample1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
       String ext1 = FilenameUtils.getExtension("/path/to/file/foo.txt");              
        try (BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("filename.txt"))) {

            // read line by line
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line).append("\n");
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.format("IOException: %s%n", e);
        }

        System.out.println(sb);

    }

}
```

Comment: Okay, but it does not mean this approach is wrong, should not be a negative answer. Adding a comment for future reader would have given the clear picture.